# How to send Json post request from java script to apach CXF Rest Service

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, cxf, webservice-client

Could anyone share the javascript example to send json post request to Apach CXF Rest Service.
I want to use the this java script for phonegap API.

Answer (score 2):

This is the post I am using for calling the rest service post method

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/restService",
  type: "POST",
  data: { data1: "xyz", data2: "xyz"},
  success: function(data){
            alert(data);
              }
});
```

This is the service snippet:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/restService")
public Collection<Obj> getPost(
        @FormParam("data1") String data1,
        @FormParam("data2") String data2){ //implementation }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you using the jquery for Ajax call ?

Comment: We are using Jquery as well as Java code for calling the REST services.

Answer (score -1):

```
Create json object

var dataObj ={"data1": "xyz", "data2" : "xyz"};

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/restService",
  type: "POST",
  data: dataObj,
  success: function(data){
            alert(data);
              }
});



@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/restService")
public Collection<Obj> getPost(
        @RequestBody DataObject dataObj){ //implementation }


Your DataObject class will look like

Class DataObject {
     private String data1;
     private String data2;

     public void setData1(String data1){
        this.data1 = data1;
     }

     public String getData1(){
         return this.data1;
     }

public void setData2(String data2){
        this.data2 = data2;
     }

     public String getData2(){
         return this.data2;
     }

}
```

Comment: No mention of spring was mentioned in the OP's question so @RequestBody is of no use.